# Mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an interesting question. For example I have a mongo collection with `start_date` and `end_date`. I need to create an aggregation query (or mapReduce) which will return an array of arrays with overlapped dates.

For example:

collection:

```
[{
  _id: 1111111,
  start_date: '10/04/2016',
  end_data: '13/04/2016'
},
{
  _id: 2222222,
  start_date: '11/04/2016',
  end_data: '20/04/2016'
},
{
  _id: 3333333,
  start_date: '10/05/2016',
  end_data: '13/05/2016'
},
{
  _id: 44444444,
  start_date: '12/05/2016',
  end_data: '15/05/2016'
},
{
  _id: 55555555,
  start_date: '18/04/2016',
  end_data: '22/04/2016'
}]
```

should return

```
[[1111111, 2222222], [3333333,44444444], [2222222, 55555555]]
```

Comment: what if you have more than 2 documents overlapping ?

Comment: No, you can't do that with aggregation, you'll need to do it in the application.

Comment: Impossible? nahhh...  How about : project (put the 2 dates in an array) > Unwind on that array > Group by date > match if one date is start and the other is end > addToSet thesw grouped ids  ...... It's the Global idea, I'll try giving the exact code.

Comment: VonD yes, it can be more than just 2 documents overlapping. BanksySan, I know that it's possible. Ludovic it would be great if you could provide any example, I like your idea! Maybe it's also possible with stored proc?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that would do, would have to try with real data to validate.

I post it as a general idea, please anyone validate and fix the answer if you have something clearer.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project: {
        _id:$_id,
        dates: [{no:1, date:$start_date},{no:2,date:$end_date}]
}},
{$unwind: $dates},
{$group: _id: $dates.date ,
        start_dates: {$addToSet: {$cond:{if:{$eq:[1, $dates.no]}, 
            then: [$_id], 
            else: null}}},
        end_dates: {$addToSet: {$cond:{if:{$eq:[2, $dates.no]}, 
            then: $_id, 
            else: null}}}
},
{$match: {$start_dates.1:{$exists:true}, 
        $end_dates.1{$exists:true}}}
]), //At this point you have objects like { aDate, [lst of ids with that date as start], [lst of ids with that date as end]}
{$unwind: $start_dates},
{$group: {_id: {date:$_id, id:$start_dates.1}, // You still have 1 array of array per dates, you can always put "_id: 1" to have only 1 array as answer
        res: {$addToSet:{$start_dates: {$each: $end_dates}}}}
}
```